# Find $C$ such that $a^{1/p}b^{1/p}\leq c (a+b)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

> Let $a,b$ be positive real numbers.
>
> Let $p$ be an integer such that $p\geq2$. Is there a positive constant $C$ such that
> $$a^{1/p}b^{1/p}\leq C (a+b)?$$

If $p=2$, by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality we have
$$\sqrt{ab}\leq \frac{1}{2}(a+b).$$

Comment: But $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary.

Comment: To add as a side note to the answers you've got below, I don't believe your generalisation from $p=2$ to an arbitrary $p$ is the "right" one. Note that you could've equally asked for $a^{1/p}b^{1/p}\le C(a+b)^{2/p}$ but in *that* case the inequality stays homogeneous in $a$ and $b$ (in other words - preserves the property that, if it holds for some $a, b$ it also holds for $ka, kb$ for any $k>0$), so it won't suffer for the same problems when $a,b$ are very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question as-is: no, there is not.

Consider the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}a^{\frac{1}{x}}=1$$

Whereas $a$ and $b$ can be arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = a^{\frac{1}{p}}, y = b^{\frac{1}{p}}\implies a = x^p, b = y^p\implies \dfrac{\sqrt[p]{ab}}{a+b}= \dfrac{xy}{x^p+y^p}= f(x,y)$. If $p = 2 \implies C = \dfrac{1}{2}$. If $p > 2$. Let $x = y \implies f(x,x) = \dfrac{1}{2}x^{2-p}\to \infty $ when $x \to 0^{+}$. Thus $f(x,y)$ is unbounded and so **no** C exists for $p > 2$.